# CSS fixed y-axis only

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, fixed

I'm working on a project that has a navbar. The navbar has to be fixed when scrolling through the page for easy access. The problem is, that when I narrow the screensize of my browser and I scroll to the right, the navbar stays fixed and buttons on the right of the navbar can't be accessed. I've searched the internet and couldn't find a solution. I did found something about fixing the X-axis, but jQuery was the only solution and I know nothing about jQuery, so I couldn't change the code to work for Y-axis too.

Comment: Some sample code would be nice but I can tell you now: use percentages for initial page load, use `@media` queries for different browser sizes etc and if you want the client to be able to resize the browser; then a JavaScript function will be needed for that action.

Comment: I want to achieve something like the second div on this example http://demo.rickyh.co.uk/css-position-x-and-position-y/

Comment: position: fixed with top/left fixed position. F12 tools FTW!

Answer (score 1):

```
#boxToFloat{
    position:fixed;
    left:10%;
    top:10%;
    z-index:100;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #FCFCFC;
    background:#333333;
    content:'tudhur!';//forgive my comical sense &amp; spelling :)
}
```

Comment: If I scroll to the right, the div still scrolls with me, and THAT is the problem.

Comment: @maximilidaan check this jquery script out for detection the scroll position. I'd recommend using an if statement to detect the scroll positionLeft not being =0. Then set position:fixed to position:static. That should work. Then obviously a function to return the CSS to default.